# Out of memory Exception in NodeJS (Javascript) with the below program

Tags: javascript, node.js

> ERROR : <--- JS stacktrace ---> Cannot get stack trace in GC. FATAL
>   ERROR: Scavenger: semi-space copy  Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory.

Out of Memory ? I have a JS code which calculate all combinations of an array to a sum =610. But the code works fine up to target 200 later it breaks. Can anyone Help me to get desired Result.

```
function combinationSum(candidates, target) {
    var result = [];

    if(candidates == null || candidates.length == 0) return result;

    var current = [];
    candidates.sort();

    combinationSumHelper(candidates, target, 0, current, result);

    return result;
}

function combinationSumHelper(candidates, target, j, curr, result){
    if(target == 0){
        var temp = curr.slice();
        result.push(temp);
        return;
    }

    for(var i=j; i<candidates.length; i++){
        if(target < candidates[i])
            return;
        curr.push(candidates[i]);
        combinationSumHelper(candidates, target - candidates[i], i, curr, result);
        curr.pop();
    }
}

console.log(combinationSum([1,2,3,4,5,6],610).length);
```

Comment: You're calling the function from inside that function with a loop, of course there isn't enough memory

Comment: `candidates.sort();` sorts strings, I'm pretty sure that is not what you wanted. See [How to sort an array of integers correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007/1048572)

Comment: @Bálint There's nothing wrong with recursion. As long as `candidates` only contains positive values, it's bound to terminate.

Comment: So what can be done in this case should i remove sorting logic or do my own customize sorting ?? @Bergi

Comment: i tried to remove candidates.sort() method , still it fails

Comment: Do you really want to get all combinations of 610 x `1`, 608 x `1` + 1 x `2` etc until 2 x `5` + 100 x `6`?? There are a lot of them - more than your memory can handle.

Comment: Yes . I do want to .